# Can I add elements to an html page using flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a program with a search feature that returns a list of strings and I would like to add them all to the website and for hem to be custom links using the a tag. How would I add elements to an html page if I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flask goes with Jinja. You should use `for loop` in Jinja to create an  tag for each item in your list for example

```
{% for link in list_links %}
    <a href="{{link}}"> {{link}} </a>
{% endfor %}
```